# Expected duration of interactions between two aircraft

Tags: probability

I want to calculate the expected duration of interactions between two aircraft.

Here, 'interaction' is defined as the simultaneous presence of two aircraft in the same region.

Now, we only look at how long each aircraft is in the specific region during the hour and considers that each aircraft may have passed through that same region at any time during the hour.

In these conditions, if $t_a$ and $t_b$ are the recorded durations of aircraft ($a$) and ($b$) in the region during the hour, then **the expected duration (in hours) of the interaction between aircraft $a$ and $b$ is equal to the product $t_a \times t_b$  $.\;$**

So the expected duration of one interaction between two aircraft which each spend three
minutes in the region ($1/20$  of one hour) is: $$\frac{1}{20}\times\frac{1}{20} = \frac{1}{400}\;\; (0.0025\; hours)$$

If the two aircraft in the region each spend three minutes in the region then the expected duration of the interactions ($a$ with $b$ and $b$ with $a$) during the one hour period is: $$2\times(\frac{1}{20}\times\frac{1}{20}) = \frac{1}{200}\;\; (0.005\; hours)$$

My problem is, why the expected duration of the interaction between two aircraft is just a product of the duration(transit time) $t_a \times t_b$?